# JavaScript Google maps api не обновляет infowindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

Есть такой код:

```
marker.addListener('click', function(e) {
    closeAllInfoWindows();
    infowindow.open(marker.get('map'), marker);
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
    geocoder.geocode({'location': e.latLng}, function(results, status) {
          infowindow.open(marker.get('map'), marker);
          if (status === 'OK') {
            if (results[1]) {
              console.log(results[0].formatted_address)
              console.log(results[0].address_components[0].long_name)
              console.log(results[0].address_components[1].long_name)
              cont  =  infowindow.content
              console.log(cont)
              regex = new RegExp(/<small class=\"grey-500\">(.*?)<\/small>/g)
              cont = cont.replace(regex, 
                                  ('<small class="grey-500">'+
                                   results[0].address_components[1].long_name + ', ' + 
                                   results[0].address_components[0].long_name +
                                   '</small>')
                                  ).toString()
              console.log(cont);
            } else {
              window.alert('No results found');
            }
          } else {
            window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
          }
        });

    closeAllInfoWindows();

    infowindow.setContent(cont);
    infoWindow.setPosition(e.latLng);

    infowindow.close(marker.get('map'), marker);
    infowindow.open(marker.get('map'), marker);
  });
```

"Почти работает".

То есть адрес в infowindow появляется, и даже правильный... Но... После второго клика. По первому клику после загрузки карты адреса нет вообще, по второму клику повляется, затем запаздывает на каждом из маркеров на 1 клик...

В консольку content для infowindow сыпется правильный.

При этом еще выплёвывает такую ошибку:

> InvalidValueError: setContent: not a string; and

А вот то, что логирует cont:

```
11:04:42.887 map4.html:162 <small class="grey-500"></small>

11:04:42.897 map4.html:162 <small class="grey-500">Красногорский бульвар, 13</small>
```

Подскажите, в чем тут грабли?

Comment: Дело в асинхронности функции geocode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело было в асинхронной работе **geocoder**.

Сделал колбэк, заработало как надо:

```
 marker.addListener('click', function(e) {

    FindAddr(e.latLng, function(data) {
    regex = new RegExp(/<small class=\"grey-500\">(.*?)<\/small>/g);
    infowindow.setContent(infowindow.content.replace(regex, data.Addr.toString()));
    infoWindow.setPosition(e.latLng);
    infowindow.open(marker.get('map'), marker);
    console.log(data);

    });

  });

}
}

function FindAddr(coodrs, callback)
{
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    geocoder.geocode({ 'location': coodrs }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        addr = '<small class="grey-500">'+ results[0].address_components[1].long_name + ', ' + results[0].address_components[0].long_name +'</small>'
            callback({ Status: "OK", Addr: addr });
        }
    });
}
```